# C# Convert my JsonSchema's Properties to Json Schema and add new fields on the fly

Tags: c#, json, jsonschema

I created my own JsonSchema with some standard properties.

```
    public class JsonSchema
{
    public SchemaType Type { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Const { get; set; }
    public IList<Dictionary<string, object>> Properties { get; set; }
    public IList<object> Enum { get; set; }
    public IList<JsonSchema> Items { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Required { get; set; }
    public IList<JsonSchema> AllOf { get; set; }
    public IList<JsonSchema> AnyOf { get; set; }
    public IList<JsonSchema> OneOf { get; set; }
}
```

and I need to convert it to Json Schema string.

I'm using the JsonConvert.SerializeObject to convert it.
Almost everything is Ok, but the property 'Properties' is being converted to an array of JsonSchema as follow:

```
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": [
        {
          "f_1022": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "Zona",
            "oneOf": [
              {
                "title": "Urbana",
                "description": "Urbana",
                "const": "o_1043"
              },
              {
                "title": "Rural",
                "description": "Rural",
                "const": "o_1044"
              },
              {
                "title": "Periurbana",
                "description": "Periurbana",
                "const": "o_1045"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "f_1023": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "Etnia/Cor"
          }
        },
      ]
    }
```

And I need the result be like this:

```
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": 
      {
          "f_1022": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "Zona",
            "oneOf": [
              {
                "title": "Urbana",
                "description": "Urbana",
                "const": "o_1043"
              },
              {
                "title": "Rural",
                "description": "Rural",
                "const": "o_1044"
              },
              {
                "title": "Periurbana",
                "description": "Periurbana",
                "const": "o_1045"
              }
            ]
          },
          "f_1023": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "Etnia/Cor"
          }
    }
}
```

Note that the last Json Properties don't have the brackets.

How can I make the JsonConvert convert like the last Json Schema?

Thanks

Comment: You need to change `Properties` type to `Dictionary<string, object>`.

Comment: LOL... of course. ty

Comment: Why create your own and not use an existing implementation?  There's a lot more to it than just the model.  Here's mine: [JsonSchema.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonSchema.Net/) ([documentation](https://gregsdennis.github.io/json-everything/usage/schema-overview.html))